# Phonegap build - unable to install iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

I'm just before launching a mobile app using **Phonegap Build**, and I have issues with the iOS build.

**Everything works just fine if I use the development certificates** (so it seems the app code is OK), but when I change them to distribution certificate, the build succeeds, but I cannot download it with the QR code provided. I tried installing it with the .ipa file, I tried recreating the certificates (provisioning profile also), and everything, but I get the following error when I try to install:

**Unable to install at this time, try again later.**

My Phonegap Build is set to cli-6.5.0, and I try to install it on an iPad with iOS 10.3.3.

I cannot imagine that there are problems with the certificate (I'm not the manager of the account, but an admin), the Android version works just fine.

The solution uses the phonegap-plugin-push plugin (v1.10.5) - and that also works in dev build. I browsed possible solutions, but I'm here after trying all the suggestions I found.

If more info is needed, please tell me!

Comment: the certificates you created are distribution certificates or development certificates ?

Comment: which QR code provided do you mean? explain this part. ANyway, iOS doesn't support phonegap-push-plugin below the version 2.x

Comment: Thank you both, now I think I know the answer: no testing on device with AppStore DISTRIBUTION certificate. I know this should be a basic thing, but it seems "I skipped class when they told it, and had to learn it the hard way".

Comment: QR code is provided by Phonegap Build - you can download and install the .ipa and .apk files by using a QR code scanner. But this could not be done with the build signed by an AppStore Distribution certificate.

Comment: And actually iOS 10.3.3 does support phonegap-plugin-push 1.10.5 - two devices (iPhone SE and iPad mini 4) are in my hand, receiving notifications right now from my app. :)